# Why OnCriticalError is called in DirectX version of XAudio2?

Tags: c++, audio, visual-c++, directx, xaudio2

My game app uses XAudio2.lib and was targeted for Windows 8 and Windows 10. The code was as follows:

```
#include <Xaudio2.h>
HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create(&s_audioEngine, 0);
hr = s_audioEngine->CreateMasteringVoice(&s_masteringVoice);
s_audioEngine->RegisterForCallbacks(&s_callbacks);
```

and everything was fine. I could unplug headsets, and then plug it back, and there were no problems. `IXAudio2EngineCallback::OnCriticalError(HRESULT error)` had never been called.

It was fine until we decided to support Windows 7. I learnt that I have to use DirectX version of XAudio2 in this case. So I set `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` in preprocessor definitions, removed `XAudio2.lib` from dependencies and changed code to

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0602 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8*/)
#include <Xaudio2.h>
#else
#include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xaudio2.h>
#endif
```

It now launches, plays sound, but when I unplug headsets, it calls `IXAudio2EngineCallback::OnCriticalError` that means that I have to restart audio engine and recreate all the audio stuff.

I do not want to have such a pain, so I am reading MSDN, and I see:

> If you specified NULL or szDeviceId parameter to
>   IXAudio2::CreateMasteringVoice, then the system uses a Virtual Audio
>   Client to represent the audio endpoint. In this case, if the
>   underlying WASAPI rendering device becomes unavailable, the system
>   automatically selects a new audio rendering device for rendering,
>   audio processing continues, and OnCriticalError is not raised.

What does it mean? What is

> If you specified NULL or szDeviceId parameter?

Can anyone explain how do I call `CreateMasteringVoice` to avoid `OnCriticalError`?

Comment: I don't see that note.  I do see, quote: "Note that the DirectX SDK XAUDIO2 version of CreateMasteringVoice took a DeviceIndex argument instead of a szDeviceId and a StreamCategory argument. This reflects the changes needed for the standard Windows device enumeration model."  So sounds like you're screwed when you use a 5 year old SDK.

Comment: I know that CreateMasteringVoice has slightly different signatures in DX and Windows SDK. But it default params are zeroes, so it compiles just fine. So I still do not understand how to avoid error on headphones removal.

Answer (score 1):

Basically with XAudio 2.7 or XAudio 2.8, if a speaker or headphones are unplugged, WASAPI tells XAudio the endpoint is gone. The only way to recover is to destroy the entire XAudio graph and re-create it. On Windows 10, XAudio 2.9, using the 'default' device rather than a specific one, WASAPI will take care of auto migrating the endpoint so XAudio doesn't get told the endpoint has gone missing.

You can reproduce the same behavior on Windows 10 if you use `XAUDIO2_NO_VIRTUAL_AUDIO_CLIENT`.

See [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/AudioEngine) for examples of handling this 'lost device' scenario.